# How to completely stop Laravel Horizon

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

After uninstalling Laravel Horizon from my app, this command still keeps running on the server, `php horizon:work redis --name=default`. What do I do next?

Comment: You can try php artisan horizon:terminate command.

Comment: From my question, Horizon is already uninstalled

Comment: If you `kill` the process by ID, does it come up again? You need to share what OS you are using, but if it is Ubuntu or any linux based system, try using `htop`, and press `F5` so you see `tree mode`, and you will then be able to see who executed the command (if it is not the first node). Still, we need more info. I would ask this on [sf] as this is more a sysadmin question, it is not related to code at all. Are you sure you are not running `supervisord` or any similar application?

Comment: I have successfully killed the process on the server. It worked. Thanks